# Seeding multiple bounding boxes using GeoWebCache

Tags: geowebcache, geoserver-rest-api

We have a system with nationwide coverage but only need to seed major cities. I am using the RestAPI but cannot seem to find a way to seed in multiple bounding boxes with a single xml config file. It would be really useful to be able to specify multiple bounding boxes in a single seeding operation.

Comment: You can start multiple seeding processes in parallel. Or in serial if you poll the status of the running process.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i have tried that, i have  20+ bounding boxes, i just though it would be easier to seed them in one operation, every separate operation needs a thread so it soon builds up. Ideally i would just like to kick off a single operation and come back hours later when it is complete.

Comment: then you will need to add some code to the REST system (and update the docs)

Comment: That would be nice indeed. My experience years ago was that when I came back hours later the (re)seeding had stopped and GWC did not give any information where is stopped so I had to start over. Therefore I tend to run smaller jobs in a row, launched by a batch file. That way I may catch what job failed and re-run just that.

Comment: I am sorry i am not a developer so would not know how to update the REST, is it a possibility for the GeoServer roadmap?